# Service Reference in IIS

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, asmx

I know how to give service reference in Visual studio. Now I'm going to deploy the code in IIS server. there how to give Web reference (i.e Url of web service . Can any one help me.

In system 1 (Web application with web service) . system 2 (web application, web service has to fetched from system1). I can execute it in VS2008 because i can easily give service reference to system2 web application..

Comment: Why do you need this? If your code was compiled with a web reference, simply deploying it should be more than enough.

Comment: I'm getting success when i run all my code in single system. I try run in two systems connected in LAN. its FAILED

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to add the reference again when deploying, but you may wish to change the address of the service, security information, quotas, timeouts, etc. All of this is configurable.

Web/service reference information is stored in .Net configuration files (e.g. app.config and web.config). When you deploy, you can change those values as needed to point to the correct location.

### Example

Note the `address` attribute. This can be changed to the address where your endpoint resides.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <client>
        <endpoint 
            address="http://localhost/SampleServer/PersonService.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_PersonService"
            contract="People.PersonService" name="BasicHttpBinding_PersonService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Thanks TIM... If i want access a database which resides on another system connected to internet. How to code that..? I'm beginner in ASP.NET

Comment: If the database is directly accessible (on a public network or on a LAN/WAN), then you can open a connection using the `SqlConnection` object with a standard connection string. If the database is not directly available, that's more complicated. If you have a specific scenario you need help with, you can open another question.

Comment: i mean.. i need to how to access database by pointing the system IPADDRESS